# Textarea's height does not change with prepopulate text

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I have a little issue here.

I'm working in a project where I need to show a form after the user clicks in a call to action. All good so far.

The problem is that when the user clicks the button to show the form, the textarea does not resize the height according with the text and looks incomplete until the user focuses the textarea and move the arrows keys.

Here are the code and the example in Codepen

```
<div ng-app="test">
  <div class="holder" ng-controller="MainCtrl" layout="row" layout-align="center center">
    <div class="blocker" ng-show="blocked">
      <md-button class="md-raised md-warn" ng-click="toggle()">See me</md-button>
    </div>
    <div class="form" ng-hide="blocked">
      <form name="myForm">
        <md-input-container flex>
            <label>How are you</label>
            <textarea ng-model="answer1" name='answer1'></textarea>
        </md-input-container>  
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the Javascript part

```
var app = angular.module('test', ['ngMaterial']);

app.controller( 'MainCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.answer1 = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu,";
  $scope.blocked = true;
  $scope.toggle = function(){
    $scope.blocked = !$scope.blocked;
  }
});
```

http://codepen.io/Tmeister/pen/wajdgE

Maybe is an Angular Material bug or just is a CSS issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the issue is reproducible on their Demo site

Comment: Really? can you point me where please.

Answer (score 4):

Well this is an official Bug and the fix is coming.

https://github.com/angular/material/commit/5fdcf905b4355c0385a02f59d2875b93e7a18ce4

If you want to trigger the TextArea Autogrow use ng-if instead of ng-hide/ng-show

```
<div ng-app="test">
  <div class="holder" ng-controller="MainCtrl" layout="row" layout-align="center center">
    <div class="blocker" ng-show="blocked">
      <md-button class="md-raised md-warn" ng-click="toggle()">See me</md-button>
    </div>
    <div class="form" ng-if="!blocked">
      <form name="myForm">
        <md-input-container flex>
          <label>How are you</label>
          <textarea ng-model="answer1" name='answer1'></textarea>
        </md-input-container>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Working Sample: http://codepen.io/Tmeister/pen/EjLXYm

Comment: I told you the same thing dude

Comment: Yes and thank you, I just improved the response with more information.

Again, thanks dude!!